# Using a non static data member in to a non static nested class withourt using object

Tags: java, nested-class, non-static

```
class Outer
{
    int x=10;
    class Inner
    {
        void show()
        {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Outer obj=new Outer();
        Inner obj1=new Outer().new Inner();
        obj1.show();
    }
}
```

I tried making a non static nested class and tried to use non static data member of outer class in non static inner class.  I did not get that if x is non static, how i am using it without object. Kindly give me the answer?

Comment: It's not really clear from your question what the problem is. Could you clarify please?

Comment: Do you know what an inner class is?

Comment: My question is simple that if x is non static then how can i use it without any object.

Comment: and @SotiriosDelimanolis i know what nested class is thats why i asked this question.

Comment: @ManishKumar The answer is simple: `Inner` isn't static either.

Answer (score 1):

You're *not* using it without an object. Inner (non-static nested) classes have a reference to the outer object, whose `x` is used.

Comment: But i have read that inner classes have no relationship with outer so how they have reference of Outer class

Comment: Nested classes don't.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Static nested don't. Inner (non-static nested) do.

Answer (score 1):

Inner class is just a syntactic sugar to have an implicit reference to an outer class. Internally (after javac compilation) your class `Inner` looks like this:

```
static class Inner
{
    private final Outer this$0;

    public Inner(Outer outer) {
        this$0 = outer;
    }

    void show()
    {
        System.out.println(this$0.x);
    }
}
```

And when you write `Inner obj1=new Outer().new Inner();` the compiler changes it to something like `Inner obj1=new Inner(new Outer());`.